# Set data URI in TinyMCE

Tags: html, image, tinymce

TinyMCE init options

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    plugins: 'base64img image imagetools paste ...',
    relative_urls: false,
    paste_data_images: true,
    ...
};
```

`paste_data_images: true` option means that `data:url` images (inline images) should NOT be removed from the pasted contents (see [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_data_images)).
I use TinyMCE 4.2.8. Inside `base64img` plugin I've written the following code

```
var editor; // TinyMCE editor
var imgData; // base64 image data string, like "data:image/png;base64,...="
editor.setContent("<img src='" + imgData + "' />", {format: 'raw'});

// editor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHtml', false, '<img src=\'' + imgData + '\' />');  // another way
```

to [embed an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) which is loaded in memory as base64 string. After the command is executed img src is **magically** converted into `'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/...'`. **Why?**

It works (images are displayed), but I want to store images as `data:` rather than upload them to server and store as `blob`. **How to change this behaviour?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image is saved internally as `'data:image/png;base64,...='`, so you don't need to worry. No uploading is performed, `'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/...'` is used for displaying an image info only.